# Limit involving $x$ raised to $\sin (1/x)$

Tags: calculus, limits

the limit as $x \to \infty$ of $x ^{\sin(1/x)}$

I see this is an infinity to zero situation, and I so I know this will be an $e^{\text{something}}$ sort of answer and that my next step would look something like:
limit as $x$ goes to infinity of $\ln(x^{\sin(1/x)})$... what is my next step and how do I proceed?

Thanks much!

Comment: How do you define $(\sin x)^{1/x}$ when $\sin x <0$?

Comment: Hi Kavi, there was a mistake in my original post. Apologies.

Comment: Are you looking for $x ^{\sin(1/x)}$?

Comment: Hi @gimusi so (1/x) is raised as well

Comment: @jackbenimbo $x\cdot (\sin x)^{1/x}?$

Comment: so it is: x^sin^(1/x)

Comment: @jackbenimbo What is the argument for sine? You should edit your question, it is not clear what youare asking for.

Comment: @jackbenimbo $\sin^{\frac1x}$ is absolutely meaningless!

Comment: Hi @gimusi, I found the correct problem. My greatest apologies.

Comment: @jackbenimbo Also $\sin*(1/x)$ is meaningless, maybe it is $\sin(1/x)$?

Comment: @gimusi that is correct!

Comment: @gimusi I have updated my question

Comment: @jackbenimbo Ok that was my first interpretation!

Comment: @gimusi see, I appreciate your edits and sticking with me.

Comment: @jackbenimbo Your idea to use logarithm is a correct way, I've indicated a way to proceed by that.

Comment: I see, I can use LH! This was my gap! Thank you again!

Comment: @jackbenimbo Refer to standard limit whenever you can and do not use l'Hopital too much for any kind of limit! Bye

Comment: @jackbenimbo Also follow the suggestion given here for the next questions https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question and learn https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Will do. One quick question which may not illicit a quick response..for the limits I've worked with thus far in calc 1/2, LH has been a life saver. Why do you recommend against it?

Comment: @jackbenimbo To learn limits it is important to recognize the standard limit as for example as $x\to 0$ $\sin x/x=1$, $(1-\cos x)/x^2=1/2$, $x\log x=0$ which can be proved independently (of course you should study these proof). L'Hopital is nice for some situation but by the blind use of it you can't learn to manipulate properly the limit by that. A better tool is Taylor's expansion, maybe you'll learn it later. Bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that

$$x ^{\sin(1/x)}=e^{\sin \left(\frac1x\right) \log x}=e^{\frac{\sin \left(\frac1x\right)}{\frac1x} \cdot \frac{\log x}{x}}\to e^{1 \cdot 0}=e^0=1$$

indeed since $t=\frac1x \to 0$

$$\frac{\sin \left(\frac1x\right)}{\frac1x}=\frac{\sin t}{t}\to 1$$

and it easy to show (for example by l'Hopital)

$$\frac{\log x}x \to 0$$

Comment: Another way to show that $(\log x)/x\to 0:$  For $1<n<x$ we have $\log x$ $=\int_1^x(1/y)dy=$ $\int_1^{x/n}(1/y)dy+\int_{x/n}^x(1/y)dy<$ 
 $\int_1^{x/n}1dy+\int_{x/n}^x (n/x)dy=$ $=(x/n-1)+(x-x/n)(n/x)=(x/n)+n-2. $ So for all $x>n^2>1$ we have $0<(\log x)/x <$ $<((x/n)+n-2)/x=$ $1/n+(n-2)/x<$ $2/n.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes of course there are best way I’ve suggested l’Hopital in that case since it is straightforward and moreover this is a standardlimit which should well known and already proved. Another (basic) way is by $x=e^y$ and then $y/e^y\to 0$ from $n/e^n\to 0$ which can proved by induction. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Consider $$y=x^{\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\implies \log(y)={\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}\log(x)$$ Now, use Taylor expansion for large $x$ (or use equivalents)
$${\sin \left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}=\frac{1}{x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^3}\right)$$ then 
$$\log(y) \sim \frac{\log(x)}x\to 0 \qquad \text{making}\qquad y \to 1$$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, note: $\sin \frac 1x<\frac 1x, x>0$. Then:
$$\left(\sin \frac 1x\right)^{\sin \frac 1x}<\left(\frac 1x\right)^{\sin \frac 1x}<x^{\sin \frac 1x}<x^{\frac 1x}, x>1$$
Taking limit at $x\to\infty$:
$$1\le \lim_{x\to\infty} x^{\sin \frac 1x}\le 1.$$

Also: See this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1923196/find-lim-x-to-infty-x-sin1-x).

Comment: This is an awesome shortcut! Thanks so much

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck.